# using code behind to fill grid in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

Is there something like

```
MyGrid.row[1].col[1] = "mytext"
```

in order to fill a *grid* with data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to position a control in a Grid using code:

```
var textBlock = new TextBlock { Text="mytext" };
Grid.SetColumn(textBlock, 1);
Grid.SetRow(textBlock, 1);
myGrid.Children.Add(textBlock);
```

Comment: so in Grid.SetColumn(textBlock, 1); I define what column the new textBlock will be in?

Comment: Note that it is a static method on the Grid class.

Comment: If I want to add a TextAlignment for textBlock, how can I do that?
`var textBlock = new TextBlock { Text="mytext"; TextAlignment="Left" };` doesn't work (Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Windows.TextAlignment')

Comment: @user1031178 - Use this: `var textBlock = new TextBlock { Text="mytext", TextAlignment=TextAlignment.Left };` Note the `,`! Just type `TextAlignment=` and code completion will suggest the correct enum type.

Answer (score 0):

There is no DataGrid in the Windows Phone SDK, but there is a Grid control that you use for page layout.  Since you did mention that your scenario is data-driven, I would suggest using the ListBox and data binding.